# Article submission websites

Tags: marketing

I recently wrote a book about an open source software library. The book is published and available in bookshops, so now marketing has the highest priority.

I have the idea to submit articles about the aforementioned open source project on popular websites targeting IT professionals. In return I would like to have a shameless plug of my book.

Do you know any websites that fit the profile? Preferably these websites should have a fast, easy and painless article submission process.

Comment: While this is likely on-topic here, [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) may be a better place for the subject-matter expertise of what places accept technical articles and will plug your book in return.  The answers you are likely to get here are more generalized, since our expertise is writing not programming.

Answer (score 2):

Check out duotrope.com

Has everything about submissions to magazines and online. It also
has a submission manager too.

Comment: Where is the information about submissions to magazines and online? Do I need to sign up to see it? I don't see anything except info about what services you get when you sign up.